# ''to master the Japanese Language'' or ''to master Japanese language'' which way is the correct way?

Tags: japanese

I want to say that I want to master the Japanese Language while learning in Japan. But sometimes it feels odd to the Japanese instead of Japanese.
I want to master Japanese Language by going Japan and learn it there. 
Is this correct?

Comment: "the" is correct. If you drop "language" then the opposite is true.

Comment: @PaulChilds I agreed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Japanese languauge, the French language, the German language, etc. It always takes the definite article **the**.

Answer (score -1):

To master the Japanese language.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange! Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer